# .Net float to double conversion

Tags: .net

Can anyone explain why the third output below prints out a value that is 128 from expected value?

I ran the following code with Target framework = .NET Framework 4

CODE:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float f = 3510000000f;
        double d = 3510000000d;

        Console.WriteLine("f = {0:f1}", f);
        Console.WriteLine("d = {0:f1}", d);
        Console.WriteLine("f converted to a double = {0:f1}",
            Convert.ToDouble(f));
        Console.WriteLine("f converted to a double using strings = {0:f1}",
            Convert.ToDouble(f.ToString()));
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

`3510000000f` represented in bits is `1101 0001 0011 0110 0101 1001 1000 0000`. You have a number with 25 bits of precision, and .Net floats only have 24 bits of precision. Therefore, when converting to a double, you've lost precision. In this case, it rounded up to `1101 0001 0011 0110 0101 1010 0000 0000`.

Comment: +1 That's a much clearer example than what I gave, though the relation back to the IEEE 754 representation is not obvious at first.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it is a rounding error.

In the binary representation of a floating point value, the *exponent* and the *mantissa* are separated. What this means is that internally, your number is represented as:

```
(1.634471118450164794921875) * 2^31
```

However, the first part of that number is restricted to fitting within 23 bits ([Wikipedia on 32-bit floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Single-precision_32-bit)), so we have to round to the nearest `2^-23`:

```
(1.634471118450164794921875) % (0.00000011920928955078125) = 
 1.6344711780548095703125
```

So your number is actually:

```
(1.6344711780548095703125) * 2^31
```

If we evaluate this, we get `3510000128` rather than `3510000000`.

In short, this is the same rounding error that you get when you specify `0.1`: neither can be expressed exactly given the limitations of the representation.

Answer (score 0):

To quote Jon Skeet:

> It's not that you're actually getting
>   extra precision - it's that the float
>   didn't accurately represent the number
>   you were aiming for originally. The
>   double is representing the original
>   float accurately; toString is showing
>   the "extra" data which was already
>   present.

[Convert float to double without losing precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916081/convert-float-to-double-without-losing-precision/916110#916110)