# Floating point conversions c#

Tags: c#, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Net float to double conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061836/net-float-to-double-conversion)

I though I understood floating point but can someone explain the following

```
float f = 1.85847987E+9F;
double d = Convert.ToDouble(f);
```

d is now converted to a string as `1858479872.0`. I'm assuming the extra 2 is because double cannot represent the floating point number exactly.

My question is why does it seem to be able to rerepsent the same number when assigned directly

```
double d = 1.85847987E+9;
```

and it is shown exactly as `185847987.0`

Comment: Or because the single precision float could not represent the value.  Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: There are plenty of articles here on SO about this - have a rummage.

Comment: Float can store 7 significant digits, you've got 9.  A conversion to double cannot magically recover what was lost.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) can, and [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) cannot represent `1.85847987E+9` precisely.

> Why the compiler doesn't complains about "float f = 1.85847987E+9F;" if it cant represents it properly

As per C# specification, section 4.1.6 Floating point types

> The floating-point operators, including the assignment operators, never produce exceptions.

Comment: The real question then is: Why the compiler doesn't complains about "`float f = 1.85847987E+9F;`" if it cant represents it properly !

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet - Properly or exactly?  If there is no data type that can represent 1/7 exactly do you just pick a different number?  The value is within the range of _float_, so it is acceptable.

Comment: @Nicolas, This is in line with c# specification. It specifies various rules for exceptional cases. For non exceptional cases with high precision range, Compiler just decreases the precision instead of producing any exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not double but float. Float is limited to 32 bit, while double uses 64 bit for precision.

Answer (score 0):

Because a float exists out of a sign, mantissa and exponent. See [Jon Skeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390072/266143) how to extract those values.

For `1.85847987E+9F`, the mantissa is `7259687` and the exponent is `8`. Then `mantissa << exponent` equals `1858479872`. Since the precision for a float is [limited to 7 digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=VS.100).aspx), the value of any digit beyond 7 digits depends on the implementation, not the input. You can test this easily by inputting `123456789F`.

Comment: If I have a float to start with then what is the most accurate way of converting to a string `code`Convert.ToDouble(1.85847987E+9F).ToString() or 1.85847987E+9F.ToString()