# C# Float to Double

Tags: c#, floating-point, double

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
           double y = 23.12F;
           Console.WriteLine(y);
           Console.Read();
}
```

why value of y shows 23.1200008392334 instead of 23.12

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = -9; uint j = (uint)i;
        Console.WriteLine(j);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

How j shows value 4294967287

Comment: Your second example seems very strange. Your are converting a negative number in a type that does not support negative number

Comment: The [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) of -9 is: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0111. Take this number into a calculator that can convert binary into decimal and you get 4294967287 ;p

Answer (score 7):

Floating points are only *guaranteed* to be exact for integer values; beyond that, **they cannot represent** all numbers; 23.1200008392334 is the closest it can get to 23.12, due to how IEEE754 *works*.

If you want "typical" handing of decimal values... use `decimal` instead:

```
decimal y = 23.12M;
```

With the `uint` - because `uint` doesn't have negative values. Instead, you are tracking backwards from the maximum value of `uint`. If you don't want this, use `checked`:

```
uint j = checked((uint) i);
```

or

```
checked
{
    uint j = (uint)i;
}
```

then it will explode in a shower of sparks instead. Sometimes a good thing; sometimes bad. `unchecked` is the default.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN 'that's just how double works'
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/1fcf6486-807d-4dce-8aef-7fe5268b568d/

I know that this is Java, but very similar to C# :
[Convert float to double without losing precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916081/convert-float-to-double-without-losing-precision)