# Boxing unboxing issue

Tags: java

Getting below bug in findbug:

> A boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed Below is the
>   statement:

```
deliveryCost = new Double(cost);
```

where `cost` is float type.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Is it of type `Float` or `float`?

Comment: Please provide more code. Is the variable `deliveryCost` a `double` or `Double`?

Comment: Isn't double and Double the same (just an alias)?

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep:  **No**.  One is an object wrapper, the other is a primitive.  There's a pretty sizable difference.

Comment: @Makoto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep: In C#, `double` is just an alias for `System.Double`, and there is no special name for a boxed `double`. In Java, `double` is the name of the primitive (value) type, while `Double` is the name for a boxed (reference) type for `double`.

Comment: Well string or double doesn't matter but I truely don't know the difference in java - so i guess you're right. Thanks also to other posters :)

Comment: Don't use a `float` if you can use a `double`  A double has half a trillion times the accuracy and the memory difference isn't worth worrying about 99% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

That message is a little odd.  I'm not sure exactly why you're getting it.  But one thing you should change is this:

```
deliveryCost = Double.valueOf(cost);
```

See if the message goes away when you do that.  When you say `new Double(...)` it's like telling java, "please, allocate a brand new object for me, even if you can reuse one and get the same effect".  It's usually not necessary to do.

Comment: double deliveryCost = 0.0; and float cost

Comment: in that case, maybe this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916081/convert-float-to-double-without-losing-precision