# Java: Adding 2 float numbers and get the result as double

Tags: java, floating-point, double

As I know double numbers reserve 64-bit in memory. Float numbers reserve 32-bit.

I tried the following:

```
double result=0.1f+0.3f;
System.out.println(result);
```

And as a result it prints `0.4000000059604645`. Is the data from the next memory block (32 first bits and the next 32)?
 
Is it something else?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/916110/1426079

Answer (score 8):

This line:

```
double result=0.1f+0.3f;
```

first converts the strings "0.1" and "0.3" to `float` values, then adds the two `float` values using the rules for `float`, and then finally converts the result to a `double` to do the assignment. The conversion of the float literals to `float` values introduces rounding error. (Just like 1/3 has an infinite, repeating expansion in base 10, 1/10 and 3/10 have infinite, repeating expansions in base 2, and cannot be represented exactly in either `float` or `double`.) The `float` addition may introduce a bit more error (pun intended). The widening expansion from `float` to `double` is exact, but the system then assumes that the expanded resolution contains meaningful data.

If you want the addition to be done using the rules for `double`, then you need to convert at least one of the operands to `double` first, either with a cast or by using a `double` literal:

```
double result=0.1f+0.3d;
```

In the above, 0.3 will be converted to a `double` to full `double` precision; 0.1 will be converted to a `float` and then widened to a `double`, resulting in a `double` value that has more rounding error than would `0.1d`. Most compilers would do this at compile time.

Compiling this code with Oracle's javac compiler (version 1.7.0_11, default settings):

```
public class Foo1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double dff = 0.1f + 0.3f;
        double dfd = 0.1f + 0.3d;
        double ddd = 0.1d + 0.3d;
        System.out.println("dff=" + dff);
        System.out.println("dfd=" + dfd);
        System.out.println("ddd=" + ddd);
        System.out.println("dff==dfd: " + (dff == dfd));
        System.out.println("dff==ddd: " + (dff == ddd));
        System.out.println("dfd==ddd: " + (dfd == ddd));
        System.out.println("ddd==0.4: " + (10*ddd == 4));
    }
}
```

produces bytecode that starts like this (using javap -c to disassemble):

```
ldc2_w        #2                  // double 0.4000000059604645d
dstore_1
ldc2_w        #4                  // double 0.4000000014901161d
dstore_3
ldc2_w        #6                  // double 0.4d
dstore        5
```

and produces this output:

```
dff=0.4000000059604645  
dfd=0.4000000014901161  
ddd=0.4  
dff==dfd: false  
dff==ddd: false  
dfd==ddd: false  
ddd==0.4: true
```

The last line shows "true" because the representation errors of 0.1d and 0.3d and the rounding error of the addition (if any) happen to combine in a way that exactly matches the representation error of 0.4d. Things would not be so nice if you changed `0.3` to `0.2` (and changed `10*ddd==4` to `10*ddd==3`).

In general, regardless of whether you use `float` or `double`, there is going to be some rounding error and the results are unlikely to be exact. For extended precision, you should use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). If you just need clean-looking output, use a format specifier (e.g., with `System.out.printf()` or `String.format()`).

You should also read [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: 0.4 does not have an exact base 2 representation. In lowest terms, it is 2/5, and 5 is not a factor any power of two. The actual double bit pattern is 0x3fd999999999999a, equivalent to 0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625. All that the final "true" means is that the value of ddd is the closest double to decimal 0.4.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - Good catch. I don't know what I was thinking. I rephrased that part of the answer. It's interesting, though, that 10*(0.4d) == 4 (exactly).

Comment: Sometimes, the rounding error on one calculation cancels out the rounding error on a previous calculation, leading to an exact result. That is what is happening on the 10*(0.4d) calculation.