# Changing java doubles to floats in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Do you know any way to easily change every `double` to `float` in a source file in eclipse (java)? I.e. how do I change

```
double a = 123.45
```

to

```
float a = 123.45f
```

I figured out the renaming `double` to `float` bit (whoa!), but how to add the `f`'s without having to go through it manually?

Comment: [Dublicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916081/convert-float-to-double-without-losing-precision)?

Comment: @Gerret i would say no dublicate

Comment: Find and replace dialog accepts Regex.. so it can be done with Regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regular expression-based search and replace might save you. Search for

```
double\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*([\-\d.e]+)\s*;
```

and replace with

```
float $1 = $2f;
```

This will take care of literals; you may also wish to replace other kinds of expressions, adding a cast operator. Once you are done with literals, use a similar regex:

```
double\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*(.+)\s*;
```

and replace with

```
float $1 = (float) $2;
```

Definitely far from foolproof, but it may save you a lot of time.

Comment: +1 I tested and it works with slight modification `double\s(\w+)\s=\s(.+?);`

Comment: this won't work in this case `double a= myclass.getDoubleValue()`

Comment: You are right, but it can be fixed with a similar regex after the literals are fixed first.

Answer (score 0):

`Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(123.45D));` Hehe

Answer (score -1):

You can cast it

```
Double d = 1.0
float f = (float)d
```