# Assigning floating value to a double value

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I was referring [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) Oracle documentation. While trying to execute the following,

```
 public static void main(String args[]){

    float f = 1.1f;
    double df = 1.1f;

    System.out.println("f=" + f);
    System.out.println("df=" + df);

    f = 1.5f;
    df = 1.5f;
    System.out.println("f=" + f);
    System.out.println("df=" + df);
 }
```

Output is

```
f  = 1.1
df = 1.100000023841858
f  = 1.5
df = 1.5
```

Why the second line of output is showing an approximate value. But not for fourth line.
How the value is getting calculated?

Comment: BTW `1.1f` is a `float` literal, assigning it to double can be misleading.

Comment: The first one just does not show you that it has the same approximate value http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: `df` is this `1.500000000000000` actually, zeros are skipped

Comment: for more info about floating point representation, refer to ieee 754 standard

Comment: @mangusta: Thanks for ieee 754 hint. http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/

Comment: Your question is really about **printing** a single-precision value as a double-precision value. In a nutshell, Java prints just enough digits in order to determine the single- or double-precision value exactly. When you print `1.1f` as a `double`, the type has more precision so more digits are necessary to make it unambiguous which `double` exactly is meant. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916081/convert-float-to-double-without-losing-precision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `1.5` can be represented exactly in double - whereas `1.1` can't be represented exactly.

It's because of periodical digits, any (irreducible) fraction where the denominator has a prime factor that does not occur in the base requires an infinite number of digits that repeat periodically after a certain point. For example, in decimal `1/4`, `3/5` and `8/20` are finite, because `2` and `5` are the prime factors of `10`. But `1/3` is not finite, nor is `2/3` or `1/7` or `5/6`, because `3` and `7` are not factors of `10`. Fractions with a prime factor of `5` in the denominator can be finite in base `10`, but not in base `2` - the biggest source of confusion for most novice users of floating-point numbers.

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
>   requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
>   many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
>   be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits,
>   most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that
>   cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the
>   result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order
>   to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
>   characteristic feature of floating-point computation.

Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more details

Comment: How that approximate value is calculated?

Comment: But he assigns 1.1f (not 1.1) both times. Should it not be the same constant?

Comment: @starmole assigning `1.1f` to a `double` results in a less accurate than possible number which is, when printed as double precision number, so inaccurate that it prints the 000023.. part whereas printing it as `float` directly skips printing that inaccuracy because it knows that there is no more value in printing numbers beyond some point. If you were to assign `1.1` as double you would be closer to 1.1 by magnitudes because there are many more bits you could use. That would print as "1.1" then.

Comment: @starmole: The Java default for printing floating-point is to print just enough digits to uniquely identify the value in its type. In `float`, “1.1” is enough because `1.1f` (exactly 1.10000002384185791015625) is closer to 1.1 than any other `float` is. In `double`, “1.1” is not enough, because the `double` 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625 is closer to 1.1 than 1.10000002384185791015625 is, so you need more digits to get closer to the value of 1.10000002384185791015625.

Answer (score 3):

**Example**

Think about binary, and more importantly, binary when dealing with a decimal place.

```
4    2    1  .  1/2    1/4    1/8
0    0    1  .  1      0      0
```

So, as you can see, the computer can represent this without a problem. Now let's look at `1.1`.

```
4    2   1   .  1/2    1/4    1/8    1/16
0    0   1   .  0      0      0      1
```

At the moment, we have `1.0625`. As you can imagine, it's somewhat difficult to get `0.0475` exactly, but we can keep trying for sake of example:

```
4    2   1   .  1/2    1/4    1/8    1/16    1/32     1/64     1/128
0    0   1   .  0      0      0      1       1        0        0
```

Now we're up to `1.8`, so let's keep going..

```
4    2   1   .  1/2    1/4    1/8    1/16    1/32     1/64     1/128
0    0   1   .  0      0      0      1       1        1        0
```

And we've got to `0.915625`..

```
4    2   1   .  1/2    1/4    1/8    1/16    1/32     1/64     1/128
0    0   1   .  0      0      0      1       1        1        1
```

and we're at `0.9234375`.

**Explanation**

I'm sure you can see where I'm going with this. There is always going to be an error between the number you want to represent, and the number that binary *can represent*. Sometimes, you get lucky, like `1.5`, and binary has no problem representing that. Other times, you have an issue, like `1.1`, and binary just gets as close as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, as we know, the representation of a number in double is more accurate than that of the same one in float. And a float is represented in 32 bits while a double is in 64 bits. So, when a float is assigned to a double, the number is expanded from 32 bits to 64 bits. Then the  inaccurate number is represented in an accurate way. So, do you understand this a bit more?