# Will I lose precision if I cast a float with 2 decimal places to double?

Tags: java, android, floating-point-precision

In my app I have a field that accepts numbers with 2 decimal places only. I want to cast this float number to a double, so would that cause any precision loss even though I am only working with 2 decimal places? Thanks!

Comment: Casting from a `float` to a `double` might reveal imprecision that was already present, but it will never lose data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert float to double without losing precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916081/convert-float-to-double-without-losing-precision)

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I will only be dealing with numbers consisting of max 2 decimal places. Would that still be able to cause imprecisions?

Comment: Neither float nor double stores numbers with "decimal places," since they are stored in binary.  You cannot represent e.g. `0.1` exactly as a binary fraction.  If you want to store decimal numbers exactly, you must use `BigDecimal`.