# Why float value is appended extra value behind decimal point in JSONArray?

Tags: android, json

The code is as below:

```
float f = 1.7f;
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
try {
    ja.put(f);
    Log.d("json", "f=" + f);
    Log.d("json", "ja=" + ja.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output is:

```
05-16 17:49:30.559  32554-32554/com.group.home D/json﹕ f=1.7
05-16 17:49:30.559  32554-32554/com.group.home D/json﹕ ja=[1.7000000476837158]
```

If `f` is `1.0`, then the output will be `ja=1`.

Where does the `000000476837158` come from? How should I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `JSONArray#put(float)` in the [`JSONArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) class so your `f` variable is converted to a `double`.

Take a look at this question: [Convert float to double without losing precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/916081/3997816).