# JavaCast float rounds generously

Tags: coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

I calculate sums and put these into an Excel sheet I generate using POI library in Coldfusion. As the Java library expects typed vars I always call `setCellValue( JavaCast( "float", myVar ) )`. I was made aware of a rounding error by `.03`. Way bigger than differences typically known after casting to float.

```cfml
<cfset s = 601761.66>
<cfoutput>
#s#<br>
#JavaCast( "float", s )#<br>
#LSNumberFormat( JavaCast( "float", s ), ".0000000" )#<br><br>
</cfoutput>
```

- The first line prints `601761.66`
- The second rounds to `601761.7`
- The third however prints: `601761,6875000` which is equal to `601761,69` and by `.03` larger than the value I put in.

I know, `LSNumberFormat` returns a string. I called it just for comparison. POI seems to store the float value, Excel eventually displays the value as LSNumberFormat does.

How can I pass a value to `setCellValue` that is so close to my value that at least the second digit after the decmal is rounded correctly?

Comment: Why would you use `LSNumberFormat` instead of `NumberFormat`?

Comment: Probably because NumberFormat only supports U.S. formatting rules.

Comment: In this case I use LSNumberformat just to see more than two decimal digits. In real life applications i use this function to get the comma as decimal separator instead of the dot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Use type double instead of float, i.e. `javacast("double", value)`

**Longer answer:**

The [Cell.setCellValue()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue(double)) method actually expects type [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) (not [Float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html)). Double is also what CF uses for [most numeric operations and functions](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/data-types-developing-guide.html) . When you pass a Float into those methods, it is implicitly converted into a Double. That conversion is (indirectly) causing the unexpected result.

The reason is that both [Float and Double are approximate types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). However, Double has greater precision:

> **float**: The float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point. ...
>
> **double**: The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point. ...

So as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/916110/104223) points out (emphasis mine):

> It's not that you're actually getting extra precision - it's that the
>   float didn't accurately represent the number you were aiming for
>   originally. The double is representing the original float accurately;
>   toString is showing the "extra" data which was already present.
>   ... [When converted to a double, it] will have exactly the same value, but when you convert it to a string it will "trust" that it's accurate to a higher precision, so **won't round off as early, and you'll see the "extra digits" which were already there, but hidden from you**

That is why both "601761.66" and "601761.6875" *seem* to be rounded to "601761.7" when cast as a float, but are displayed expected when cast as a double.

```
<cfscript>
    value1 = "601761.66";
    value2 = "601761.6875";

    WriteOutput("<br>[Float] "& value1 &" = "& javacast("float", value1));
    WriteOutput("<br>[Float] "& value2 &" = "& javacast("float", value2));
    WriteOutput("<br>[Float=>Double] "& value1 &" = "& javacast("double", javacast("float", value1)));
    WriteOutput("<br>[Double] "& value1 &" = "& javacast("double", value1));
    WriteOutput("<br>[Double] "& value2 &" = "& javacast("double", value2));
</cfscript>
```

**Output:**

```
[Float] 601761.66 = 601761.7
[Float] 601761.6875 = 601761.7
[Float=>Double] 601761.66 = 601761.6875
[Double] 601761.66 = 601761.66
[Double] 601761.6875 = 601761.6875
```

**NB:** CF uses Float.toString() and Double.ToString() to display the values via cfoutput/writeOutput/cfdump.