# Incorrect querying result via jdbc

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When querying values from Snowflake via jdbc driver snowflake-jdbc-3.12.5.jar, the result is incorrect.

1. The table definition in Snowflake:

```
create table test_dob(DOB DECIMAL(38,3),REL DECIMAL(38,5));
insert into test_dob values(0.99, 0.99);
```

2. Querying values from table 'test_dob' via jdbc driver snowflake-jdbc-3.12.5.jar;

```
.....
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:snowflake://XXXXX.aws.snowflakecomputing.com?db=testdbu", "user", "password");

......
String sql = "select dob,rel from test_dob";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next()) {
    for (int j = 1; j < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1; j++) {
      //System.out.print(rs.getString(j) + ",");
      System.out.print(rs.getDouble(j) + ",");
  }
.......
```

The querying results are:

```
 0.9900000095367432,0.99,
```

You can get that the querying value of first column("dob") is incorrect, but the second("rel") is correct.

Is it a bug for driver?

Answer (score 2):

The [right](https://alvinalexander.com/java/mysql-to-java-field-mappings-decimal-bigdecimal-scala/) `ResultSet` method to use for a SQL type of `DECIMAL` is [`ResultSet::getBigDecimal(col)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBigDecimal-int-).

By asking for a `double` type via `ResultSet::getDouble(col)` instead, you're forcing a conversion of the underlying numeric representation.

Given the differing scales (`3` and `5`) in your SQL decimal/number data types, the conversion to `double` is handled differently for each case. For the smaller scale (`3`), a [small-int type is used](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/5ad1bd73e0e1dea7403522b6d6cbe7225ebc5037/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/core/arrow/SmallIntToScaledFixedConverter.java#L35-L43) against the transferred value due to its limited bit-width, and its [double conversion](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/5ad1bd73e0e1dea7403522b6d6cbe7225ebc5037/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/core/arrow/SmallIntToFixedConverter.java#L108-L118) actually uses a float type underneath that upcasts to a double. For the larger scale (`5`), a regular integer is used and the [double conversion](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/5ad1bd73e0e1dea7403522b6d6cbe7225ebc5037/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/core/arrow/IntToScaledFixedConverter.java#L42-L50) is done directly.

Here's a pure Java (via [`jshell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm)) representation of what is going on behind the scenes

```java
~> jshell

jshell> short sv = 990; // with scale 3
jshell> (double) ((float) sv / (float) 1000l)
$n ==> 0.9900000095367432

jshell> int iv = 99000; // with scale 5
jshell> (double) ((double) iv / (double) 100000l)
$n ==> 0.99
```

> Is it a bug for driver?

The `double` conversion done in the `byte`/`short`/`int` cases can certainly be unified for improved behaviour, but it will not solve the problem beyond the use of `0.99` as a test example. Other `DECIMAL` typed numbers that cannot be represented precisely in `double` will continue to surface.

While the conversions [will yield different results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/916081/13472370) because of the bits used to represent each type, both are valid from a driver-correctness perspective **because by asking for a `double`** in place of a `BigDecimal` you are indicating that you **do not require** a precise representation of the number being retrieved.

If precision/correctness is required (such as for handling currency, or in certain scientific applications), use the following instead:

```java
System.out.print(rs.getBigDecimal(j) + ",");
```

For understanding the lossy precisions of `float` and `double` types, read: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/13472370)