# cannot convert from float to double?

Tags: java, floating-point

> The formula to calculate the area of a circumference is defined as x =
> π . R2. Considering to this problem that π = 3.14159:
>
> Calculate the area using the formula given in the problem description.
>
> Input The input contains a value of floating point (double precision),
> that is the variable R.

And for an input of 2, I should be getting x=12.5664 rounded by one number.

I tried using this simple code, but I couldn't remember what to do with the "cannot convert from double to float" error. It's been half a year since I coded.

```
package TEST;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // let A be radius
    float A = scanner.nextFloat();
    float A_2 = A * A;
    // let B be Pi
    double B = 3.14159;
    
    // let x be circumference
    float x = A_2 * B;
    
    System.out.printf("x= %.4f" + x);

    
    }}
```

Comment: If you want to use all floats, you can use `float B = 3.14159f`. Additionally, the `+` in the `printf` needs to be a comma.

Comment: That solved it, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Easy to solve: **Never use `float`**, use `double`. Unless you have very specific needs, using `float` will just cause you more headaches than it's worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the **compilation error** is the following assignment:

```
float x = A_2 * B;
```

where `B` is of type, `double` and therefore the result of the product will of type, `double` which can not be accommodated into a variable of type, `float`. Remember: `double` requires 8 bytes of space whereas a `float` variable can accommodate only 4 bytes.

After correcting this compilation error, you will encounter a **runtime error** because you have used a plus sign (`+`) instead of a comma (`,`) inside the `printf` statement.

Apart from this,

1. Always follow Java naming conventions e.g. `A` should be `a` and `A_2` should be `a2` following the conventions.
2. You can use `Math.PI` instead of using your own value for `PI`.

The following code incorporates these changes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // let a be radius
        float a = scanner.nextFloat();
        float a2 = a * a;
        // let b be PI
        double b = Math.PI;

        // let x be circumference
        double x = a2 * b;

        System.out.printf("x= %.4f", x);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
2
x= 12.5664
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
double A_2Converted = (double) A_2;
```

and use that.

source: [Convert float to double without losing precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916081/convert-float-to-double-without-losing-precision)

Comment: There is a saying that if you need to cast, you are doing it wrong.